# Clicking outside jQuery selector still activates function

Tags: jquery, css

Follow these steps at JS Riddle to see the problem:

1. Goto http://jsfiddle.net/MjrFC/1/
2. In the result area click the word "test" this opens up point 1
3. You should only be able to click the word test(point1) and the word hey(point2) but if you click the h1 tag that says Hello it goes to point 1.

THE CODE BELOW

```
    <div class="contentb">
        <h1>testing hello world</h1>
        <div class="point1">test</div>
    </div>

        point1 = '<div class="contentb"> <h1>Hello</h1><div class="point1"> test</div><div class="point2">Hey</div><h1>World</h1></div>';
        point2 = '<div class="contentb"> <div class="point1"> test</div></div>';

       var className = "Broken";
       $(document).on('click', '.contentb [class]', function () {
           $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
               className = this.className; 
               $('.contentb').html(window[className]); 

               $(this).fadeTo(250, 1.00);

           });
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `point1` and `point2` variables should not contain `contentb` div since you are appending the html to a element with class `contentb`

```
point1 = '<h1>Hello</h1><div class="point2"> test</div><div class="point2">Hey</div><h1>World</h1>';
point2 = '<div class="point1"> test</div>';

var className = "Broken";
$(document).on('click', '.contentb [class]', function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
        className = this.className; 
        $('.contentb').html(window[className]); 

        $(this).fadeTo(250, 1.00);

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cpvt9/)